# No output to client from NodeMCU/LUA HTTP Server

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

Am unable to get any output to wireless client from the web server. The [exact scripts](http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1783&p=10668&hilit=configserver#p10668) (verbatim) I'm using seem to work more gracefully and stable than any others I've tried.

Once the 3 scripts from the link above are uploaded to the NodeMCU Dev (ESP8266-12E) and I press reset, the script outputs status through the serial port as expected:

```
Communication with MCU...
Got answer! AutoDetect firmware...

NodeMCU firmware detected.
=node.hStatus = 0 (Idle)
eap()
36936
> Status = 0 (Idle)
Status = 0 (Idle)
Status = 0 (Idle)

  { repeats for 30 seconds ... }

Status = 0 (Idle)
Status = 0 (Idle)
network not found, switching to AP mode
Starting up AP with SSID: Unconfigured-2c:36
GET received
```

The above output shows me connecting to this AP with another client (GET received), but there is never any output on the client. The browser page is blank.

The function called to output the HTML page is located in configServer.lua:

```
function sendPage(conn)
  conn:send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n')
  ...
```

None of the `conn:send()` statements generate any output on the client. I've tried with multiple clients and multiple browsers. I've also set some `print()` statements within this routine and can see that it is executing fully.

Does anyone have any idea what types of problems can cause this or how to go abut troubleshooting it? It seems like these scripts worked good for others that tried them.

I run NodeMCU built using http://nodemcu-build.com. It's based on SDK v1.4.0. It seems to work good:

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: master
    commit: c8037568571edb5c568c2f8231e4f8ce0683b883
    SSL: false
    modules: adc,bit,cjson,coap,crypto,dht,enduser_setup,file,gpio,i2c,mqtt,net,node,pwm,rtctime,spi,tmr,u8g,uart,wifi
 build  built on: 2016-02-03 23:59
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.4.0
```

Comment: In addition to @gre_gor's correct answer here's the official documentation: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/net/#netsocketsend. Furthermore, you should note that the current `dev` branch has an HTTP module that simplifies your life: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/http/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for others because it worked on NodeMCU 0.9.6.

[With NodeMCU 1.4.0, multiple calls to `conn:send()` won't work.](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/730)

You need to concatenate all the data together and send it in one go.

```
conn:send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html>\n<head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n<title>Device Configuration</title></head>\n<body>\n<form action="/" method="POST">\n')
```

Or you could send another chunk of data, after the current chunk was sent, based on `conn:on("sent", send_callback)`

```
local response = {
    'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n',
    '<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html>\n<head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n<title>Device Configuration</title></head>\n<body>\n<form action="/" method="POST">\n'
}
local function sender(conn)
    if #response>0 then conn:send(table.remove(response,1))
        else conn:close()
    end
end
conn:on("sent", sender)
sender(conn)
```